# Dockerfile Entrypoint - still exiting with exec $@?

Tags: dockerfile

I'm working on a container to use megacmd (CLI syncing utility from Mega.nz, storage provider).

Relatively new to Dockerfiles, I've successfully made a dockerfile that will install MegaCMD, and login, but once it does that, it stops the container.

In my compose file I have set `tty: true`, thinking that would keep it alive, but it does not.

```
FROM ubuntu:groovy

ENV email=email@example.com
ENV password=notyourpassword

RUN apt-get update \
....more stuff here

COPY megalogin.sh /usr/bin/local/megalogin.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/usr/bin/local/megalogin.sh"]
####Works up to here but the container still stops when finished the login script
```

megalogin.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
mega-login ${email} ${password}
mega-whoami
```

What do I need to do to make this thing to stay running?
I have tried the `exec "$@"` at the end of the script but that didnt make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

So not the exact best solution, but in the compose file I put:
And it worked.

```
tty: true
stdin_open: true
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run your container append the `tail -f /dev/null` to the `docker run` command e.g.

```
docker run -d [container-name] tail -f /dev/null
```

You should then be able to exec into the running container using `docker exec [container-name] /bin/bash`